# DynamoDB: handling throttling with boto

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

According to DynamoDB docs, requests causing database throttling are automatically retried if using the supported SDKs. However, I was unable to find any mention about how boto handles throttling cases. Does boto automatically retry throttled requests or should I start catching ProvisionedThroughputExceededException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boto does automatically retry ProvisionedThroughputExceededException errors.  There is a special retry handler in the boto.dynamodb.layer1 module that handles this.  It uses shorter wait intervals and retries a maximum of 10 times.  After that, it throws a `DynamoDBThroughputExceededError` exception.  The boto library also keeps track of the total number of ThroughputExceededErrors that are caught in the attribute `throughput_exceeded_events` of the Layer1 object.

Comment: Is there a way to configure boto to wait longer, try more?

I do a full scan on a very large table, I cannot guess how much I need to provision + I only need to run this script once in a while. I'm ok with my script being slow, but right now it keeps dying because I run out of capacity.

Comment: There is a class variable on the Layer1 class (or the DynamoDBConnection class if you are using dynamodb2 module) called NumberRetries.  That is 10, by default.  You could change that value programmatically in your code.

Comment: see this, for a solution to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003350/change-the-number-of-request-retries-in-boto3