# Change the number of request retries in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

In boto3 or botocore, how do I do the equivalent of setting the number of request retries?

e.g. in boto2

```
from boto import config
config.set('Boto', 'num_retries', '20')
```

How do I do this in boto3? I've tried

```
conn._session.set_config_variable("num_retries", "20")
```

but when I then `get_config_variable("num_retries")`, `None` is returned.

Answer (score 57):

You should now be able to do this, at least for ec2 and perhaps other clients as well:

```
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(
    retries = dict(
        max_attempts = 10
    )
)

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', config=config)
```

Comment: Just adding API URL in case if anyone wants to try other parameters too. The answer works! https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html

Comment: And some SDK documentation now as well: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html

Comment: how can we do this for paginators?